# Reinitialize Getx scrollController when navigate to same page

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I use Get.offNamed to navigate to same page _ but this method called

```js
  @override
  void onClose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(_loadData);
    super.onClose();
 }
```

As a result I lose page scrolling   **How do I reset the scrollController**

the Controller :

```js
class PostsController extends GetxController with StateMixin<Posts> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  
  @override
  void onInit() {
    _getData();
    scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_loadMore);
    super.onInit();
  }

  _getData() async {}

  _loadMore() async {}

  @override
  void onClose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(_loadMore);
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

---I noticed Get.offNamed at first it reads the Controller of new page (in my case it's the same page)

```js
[GETX] Instance "PostsController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "PostsController" has been initialized
```

Then deletes the controller of old page (in my case it's the same page)

```js
[GETX] "PostsController" onDelete() called
[GETX] "PostsController" deleted from memory
```

Because of working in this order, the scrollController is lost. If it works the other way around the scrollController will be reinitialized.

**I don't know how to go to the same page after deleting the controller (Firstly) and reinitializing it (secondly), or not calling onClose() when going to the same page as replacment**

Comment: do scrollController.dispose(); in dispose()

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more so that others can understand your actual problem?

Comment: thank you, I edited the question and tried to clarify the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can try initializing your scroll controller in the `initstate` like this:

```
class PostsController extends GetxController with StateMixin<Posts> {
  late final ScrollController scrollController;
  
  @override
  void onInit() {
    _getData();
    scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_loadMore);
    super.onInit();
  }

  _getData() async {}

  _loadMore() async {}

  @override
  void onClose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(_loadMore);
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try removing the method from onClose

Comment: When removing onClose() , everything works fine, but to be honest with you, I don't know the value of .removeListener(_loadMore) after i add it  .addListener(_loadMore) .. Is this necessary or what?

Comment: The problem is happing that your controller is not getting destroyed when you navigate to the other page, but your `onClose()` method is called, That's why removing from `onClose()`. works completely fine